# Internal representation of polynomials ... similar to Maple?

Tags: polynomials, implementation-details

The internal representation of expressions is described in the Wolfram reference, as nested lists of pointers:
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BasicInternalArchitecture.html

On the other hand, this book (Heck,2003) discusses, that Maple uses directed acyclic graphs (DAGs) for polynomial representation (also implemented with nested lists of pointers):
https://books.google.hu/books?id=duXcBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=dag+heck+maple&source=bl&ots=RpxyZqPBU0&sig=fNvtZJUDHyMGKlyN_soEN1XOgwo&hl=hu&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKu-KnoqvRAhXJBiwKHc3AC_0Q6AEIGDAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

Is the Mathematica representation the same (with DAGs)? Do you know about any difference?

My experience is, that substitutions work quiet different for the two systems. Is it the different representation, or just the great handling of regular expressions in Mathematica?

Comment: The basic Mathematica "expression" is a DAG. But to be honset, this question is too broad to really give a reasonable reply. If you provide code that shows specific situations and computations, it might be easier to give some indication of what is happening internally.